# Creating apps on facebook automatically

Tags: facebook, api

Does anyone know of a way programmatically to add/remove applications?
i.e to replicate the function of the Developer App?

I can see a graph request to obtain the details of an app, but nothing to set those details.

All thoughts gratefully received....

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to add/remove as at now. The topic of your question asks about "creating apps". That is also not possible programatically. You will manually have to fill data in "creating app" case.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's possible to do